# Android studio error "Could not download bundletool.jar" at build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I try to build or sync any app in android studio, or even to just preview the app, I get the error

> Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01):

I have searched online but couldn't find anything relating to bundletool.jar. I have tried to "invalidate chaches/restart", and have also downloaded gradle manualy, and pointed to the folder, but nothing seems to work.

Ps: I am just starting in working with android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Gradle -> use default gradle wrapper and uncheck offline work

Done

Comment: Thank you!
it is prompting me to install android NDK. Will let you know how it turns out.